# Simple amplifier circuit for a synth chip

Tags: amplifier

I have bought a SID chip with the intention to build a simple synth. I'm pretty confident with the digital aspects of using it but I'm not very familiar with the analog ones and specifically I would want to convert its output signal to something that can drive head phones or be fed into a stereo.

This is the data sheet for it:
http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Commodore_SID_6581_Datasheet

The output Signal specification looks like this:

```
This open-source buffer is the final audio output of SID, comprised of the three SID
voices, the Filter and any external input. The output level is set by the output 
Volume control and reaches a maximum of approximately 3 volts p-p at a 6 volt DC
level. A source resistor from AUDIO OUT to ground is required for proper operation.
The recommended resistance is 1 KOhm for a standard output impedance. As the output 
of SID rides at a 6 volt DC level, it should be AC-coupled to any audio amplifier 
with an electrolytic capacitor in the 1-10uF range.
```

What type of circuit would I need to build in order to plug in a pair of weak head phones or feed it into a stereo? Off the shelf components and pointers to dyi projects providing this feature works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appendix C at the bottom of the datasheet link is the Typical Application Circuit.

[image]
<sub>(source: [waitingforfriday.com](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/images/thumb/7/72/SID_Typical_Application.PNG/787px-SID_Typical_Application.PNG))</sub>

Notice the top right corner listed Audio out. That's the typical circuit needed, just a 1kΩ resistor, and a 1µF electrolytic capacitor (and a plug connector). As a 3V peak to peak, basically a strong line level, it can plug into most stereo line ins, and it should drive headphones directly in an okay manner (mono of course).  You shouldn't need anything else, but I suggest using a pair of dollar store headphones first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd buy one of those China-sourced PAM8403 Class D amp modules and wire it up with a volume pot. They work great and you can get them dirt cheap.